# How to prevent viewing a view when clicking on a button (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, button, segue, firebase-authentication

I'm having a button on view that contains this condition:

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddDevice", sender: nil)
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message:"You Have to register", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in })
            self.present(alert, animated: true){}
        }
    }
```

To check whether the user is logged in or not! 
If logged in the segue should run and open the next view

If not an alert should appear to the user.

But the next view contains a function that retrieved the current user data! (Logged in user) in viewDidLoad function!

So when the user not logged in and I click to this button I keep getting crash instead of the alert!

How can I prevent viewing the next view and just present the alert! 
So I can avoid the crash?

Comment: Is the segue connected in storyboard from the button? or from the view controller?

Comment: From the button to the view controller! I did that because the same viewer connects to another view (By the views not using buttons)

Comment: I solve ittttttt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description is sounds like the `segue` is always executing, but it's not what you want.

Connect the segue from the view controller itself, name it and put the whole method inside `IBAction` connected to the button.

Something like this:

```
@IBAction func loginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if let user = user {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddDevice", sender: nil)
         }
         else {
             let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message:"You Have to register", preferredStyle: .alert)
             alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in })
             self.present(alert, animated: true){}
    }
}
```

---

**For illustration:**

- In the first image the segue is connected to the button. Therefore, every time the button is pressed it will execute the `segue`.
- In the second image the segue is connected to the view controller and the button is *only* connected to the via the `IBAction`. Therefore, the button only triggers the `action` and the action triggers the `segue`.
- This could easily checked by selecting the segue in storyboard

[image: button selected]

[image: vc selected]

Comment: Ok! You did not change anything in the code! But It has been solved after connecting the two views by the segue not the button!

Comment: Yes, I fell for it too in the past. The segue is always executed if connected by the button. Glad you solved it.

Comment: No need for the explanation! It has been solved! Thanks!

Comment: You know, if somebody else might encounter a similar problem